# Extracting a value from JSON array without keys with JSONPATH

Tags: json, jsonpath

I don't know, whether it's possible at all, but here is my problem. This is a JSON containing an array without keys:

```
{
  "SearchResults": {
    "tables": [
      {
        "rows": [
          [
            "InternalExecutionError",
            "An internal execution error occurred. Please retry later.",
            "node-prod6",
            4
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to extract `node-prod6` using JSONPATH.

In this particular case `$.SearchResults.tables[0].rows[0][2]` will do the trick, but the problem is, that I don't know in advance the number rows or their order. All I know, that `.SearchResults.tables[0].rows[0]` contains the string I need *somewhere*. However I know the pattern of what I am looking for: `node-*`, so RegEx seems to be the best way, but is it possible to do RegEx matching in JSONPATH in an array without keys? If no, thank you for confirming, if yes, please, help with the syntax.

Comment: Not sure you can do it with jsonpath, but it can be done with jq.

Comment: Nope, can't be done with jsonpath.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that much and now looking at the application, that generates this JSON output to make the format more predictable.

Comment: Why not just change the tool you use? There is jq, Jmespath, jsonic, a few others.

Comment: As often happens I'm not free in selecting the tool - I need to use whatever is available in the platform I work with. No big mystery in the scenario: one monitoring system fires alerts and sends them as json objects to another support incident management system. I want to customize the way the information is presented in the latter system, but all I can do is what possible to do with JSONPATH - that's the only tool the support incident management system has to offer.

Comment: In that case you are really stuck :( You're right - the only thing to do is to convince whoever is in charge of formatting the alert to change the format so it's compatible with jsonpath filtering...